# Not able to remove menu items as per roles in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have

Web.sitemap like this  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="" title=""  description="">
        <siteMapNode url="~/Home.aspx" title="Home"  description=" this is the home page" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/ProjectList.aspx" title="Project List"  description="Approved projects" />
        <siteMapNode url="" title="Project Choices" description="">
            <siteMapNode url="~/StudentChoices.aspx" title="Student Project Choices"  description="" />
            <siteMapNode url="~/StaffChoices.aspx" title="Supervisor Project Choices"  description="" />
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="~/AllocationList.aspx" title="Project Allocation List"  description="" />
        <siteMapNode url="" title="Submit Proposal" description="" >
            <siteMapNode url="~/submit.aspx" title="New Proposal"  description="new proposal" />
            <siteMapNode url="~/reSubmit.aspx" title="Re-Submit Proposal" description="re submit proposal"/>
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="~/StaffRecords.aspx" title="Staff Records"  description="" >
            <siteMapNode url="~/addStaff.aspx" title="Add new Staff" description="" />
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="~/StudentRecords.aspx" title="Student Records"  description="" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/Administration.aspx" title="Administration"  description="" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

I used this sitemap for creating menu items : like following :

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal"
                BackColor="#33CCFF" Font-Overline="False" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"
                Font-Size="Larger" ForeColor="Black" ItemWrap="True" StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                StaticSubMenuIndent="60px" Width="100%" OnMenuItemDataBound="Menu1_MenuItemDataBound">
                <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#9999FF" ForeColor="Black" />
                <DynamicMenuItemStyle BackColor="#0099FF" ForeColor="Black" />
                <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#0099FF" />
                <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#0099FF" ForeColor="Black" />
            </asp:Menu>


<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
```

on code be-hide i wrote following things :

```
protected void Menu1_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        //string role = Session["Roles"].ToString();
        string AdminRole = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminRole"];
        string StaffRole = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StaffRole"];
        string StudentRole = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StudentRole"];

        if (StaffRole == "Staff")
        {
            if (e.Item.Text == "Project Choices" ||
                e.Item.Text == "Staff Records" ||
                e.Item.Text == "Student Records")
            {
                Menu1.Items.Remove(e.Item);
            }
        }
    }
```

and web config like this

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="AdminRole" value="Admin"/>
        <add key="StaffRole" value="Staff"/>
        <add key="StudentRole" value="Student"/>
    </appSettings>
```

but I am still able to see those menus, I am not able find out why it's not removing, Can anyone tell me why? Show me sample code.

Comment: Please post your `web.config` `AppSettings` section for `StaffRole`.

Comment: Are you trying to hide menu items based on the role of the person viewing the menu? If so you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: I am not going to hide, i am going to remove !, for example, if current user is staff then i need to remove 3 menu items, anyway, how to decided user is staff or admin, i already wrote the code,

Comment: I don't see how you finding out wich role the user has. Are you using a Custom Membership?

Answer (score 0):

The `siteMapNode` already provide an attribute called `roles`. This attribute hold the `roles` that can access that area of the site.

For exemple, the Project list should looks like:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/ProjectList.aspx" 
 title="Project List"  
 description="Approved projects" 
 roles="AdminRole"/>
```

Theres a `Security trimming` that in conjuction with `ASP.NET Membership` can manage the access based on user roles.

You should take a look here: [ASP.NET Site-Map Security Trimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 The easiest way  to use a SiteMapProvider is  to configure with SecurityTrimmingEnabled = true.

 Add this under Web.Config file 
<siteMap enabled="true" defaultProvider ="AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider" >
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" name="AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>

try to add the roles to the site map like this
<siteMapNode url="~/StaffRecords.aspx" title="Staff Records"  description=""     roles="StaffRole">
  <siteMapNode url="~/addStaff.aspx" title="Add new Staff" description="" />
</siteMapNode>
```